# Set the minimum width for content control in an expander when collapsed

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a pdfViewer with an expander wrapped around it. I am trying to set the minimum height of content control inside expander when collapsed to 250 and when expanded set the height to the page height. 
so even if the user collapses the expander he can see a part of the document. There is no property to set the height of content control and the expander's height property as set in code below is not working.
Is there any way of achieving this?

```
 private void exPDF_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PDFCaption != null)
            {
                PDFCaption.Text = "Click to hide PDF.";
                pdfViewer.Height = this.ActualHeight; 
                exPDF.Height = this.ActualHeight; 
                var rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(sender as Expander);
                var Row = LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[rowIndex];
                Row.Height = GridLength.Auto;

            }
        }

        private void exPDF_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            if (PDFCaption != null)
            {
                PDFCaption.Text = "Click to show PDF.";
                pdfViewer.Height = 250;
                exPDF.Height = 250;
                var rowIndex = Grid.GetRow(sender as Expander);
                var Row = LayoutRoot.RowDefinitions[rowIndex];
                Row.Height = GridLength.Auto;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Which `Expander` are you using? Afaik there is no Expander among the stock controls (and the msdn docu does not list one for Silverlight). I bet the Expander you are using is not made for "still-shows-some-content-while-collapsed". So you will probably have to change the control template.

Comment: There is one that comes with silvelright toolkit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx. I did try to change the template but found it not worth the effort so Instead I am using a bordered stack panel with a toggle button and PDFViewer and then in code setting the height of row containing stack panel as auto or 250 depending upon whether its expanded or collapsed